# Constructor X in class X cannot be accessed in class Y

Tags: scala, visibility, access-modifiers

I have a case class (FSMStateEstimator) which I assume has a public default apply method. However when I try to access it from another class (FSMStateRun) I get the error in the title:

Error:(20, 19) constructor FSMStateEstimator in class FSMStateEstimator cannot be accessed in class FSMStateRun
    val learner = FSMStateEstimator(fsm)

I don't understand why it is not visible.. Isn't the default apply method public? If I uncomment the apply method in FSMStateEstimator object I get a redefinition error. I am using scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

EDIT: When I explicitrly write val learner = FSMStateEstimator.apply(fsm) I get the same error

File1

```
package estimator.HMMEstimator
....
class FSMStateRun private (fsm: SDFAInterface) extends LazyLogging {

def estimateHMM(streamSource: StreamSource): FSMStateEstimator = {
 val learner = FSMStateEstimator(fsm) //Error here
 run(learner,streamSource)
 learner.estimate()
 learner
}
}
```

File2

```
package estimator.HMMEstimator
....
object FSMStateEstimator {
 //def apply(fsm: SDFAInterface): FSMStateEstimator = new FSMStateEstimator(fsm)
}

case class FSMStateEstimator private(fsm: SDFAInterface) extends RunEstimator with Serializable { ....  }
```

Comment: the `private` keyword here `class FSMStateRun private (fsm: SDFAInterface)` makes it private

Comment: Where does "it" refer to? The apply method? I thought it was only for the constructor. Also I assume you refer to the FSMStateEstimator class not FSMStateRun. I use the apply method of the first class

Comment: The only declared constructor is the private one

Comment: I suppose then the default apply method has the access modifier of the constructor?

Comment: Maybe this changed in Scala 2.12: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50993017/14955

Comment: There is no default `apply` method for regular classes, you have declare your own in companion object, if it does not yet exists.

Comment: @IvanKurchenko FSMStateEstimator is a case class, not a regular one

Comment: @user316227 Excuse me, please, for confusing comment, I was talking about `FSMStateRun` which has private constructor.