# Restrict Construction of Scala Class

Tags: scala

Given:

```
class Foo(x: Int) {}

object Foo {
  def apply(x: Int) = new Foo(x)
}
```

Besides marking `Foo`'s constructor as `private`, how can I present a warning or compile-time failure when calling `new Foo(...)`?

In other words, I'd like to restrict (either by compile-time warning or error) construction of `Foo` to `Foo.apply`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why “besides marking Foo's constructor as private"? What's wrong with that solution?

Comment: That's what marking the constructor as private is _for_.

Comment: Value classes ignore private, no?

Comment: @KevinMeredith, no. Check update of my answer and follow the link in it for more details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In scala there are two idiomatic ways how to achieve that.

1. Constructor private to the class and companion object.

Factory has access to constructor, while anyone else doesn't:

```
class Foo private[Foo](val x: Int)

object Foo {
  def apply(x:Int) = new Foo(x)
}

val foo = new Foo(1)  // cannot compile
val foo1 = Foo(1) //compiles fine
```

2. Sealed abstract class.

In scala `sealed` class can be extended only in the same source file it is defined. 
I suggest to make `Foo` `sealed abstract class` and return anonymous child of `Foo` in object's apply method.

```
sealed abstract class Foo(val x:Int)

object Foo {
  def apply(x:Int):Foo = new Foo(x) {}
}
```

In this case `Foo` can be created nowhere except the file where it is defined.

**UPD**: Actually, this question was already [discussed on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730536/private-and-protected-constructor-in-scala).

**UPD2**: Added brief overview of both methods.

Comment: But an `abstract class` cannot be instantiated.

Comment: @KevinMeredith, that's the point. In `object Foo` you can create object of anonymous classes that extend `Foo` (that's why there are curly braces after `new Foo`), while in other files you can't do that, because `Foo` is abstract and sealed, meaning you can't create it directly and you can't extend it in order to instantiate it's child.