# private keyword has different meaning on class definition

Tags: scala

I think I had a good understanding of Scala till I find myself in this simple scenario

```
sealed abstract case class Name private(name: String)

object Name {
    def make(name: String): Option[Name] =
      if (name.nonEmpty) Some(new Name(name) {}) else None
  }
```

my question is about the `private` modifier for the class.
If I use it like this, everything works, but if I move the `private` keyword at the start, something like

`private sealed abstract case class Name(name: String)` it doesn't compile becuase gives me the following error

> private class Name escapes its defining scope as part of type
> Option[example.package.Name]

where `example.package` is the package object I'm working in.

I think I need some clarification because I'm not sure what's happening here

Comment: Hint: *what* is the keyword in front of?

Comment: @JörgWMittag `what` is not a keyword in scala, not sure what you're talking about

Comment: Jörg meant: Where is the keyword located? In front of what? This is a hint for you so that you can find the answer to your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Private and protected constructor in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730536/private-and-protected-constructor-in-scala)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```scala
sealed abstract case class Name(name: String)
```

`Name` effectively denotes both

- the name of the class
- the default constructor for that class

```scala
sealed abstract case class Name private(name: String)
```

declares that the class is public, but the constructor is private (i.e. can only be called from within that class or its companion object).

```scala
private sealed abstract case class Name(name: String)
```

declares that the class is private (which implies that the constructor is also private).

Comment: It is worth adding that you can still create instances of `case class private Name` outside the companion object because there is an automatic `public` constructor for a `case class`. Private constructors only really make sense for bare `class` definitions.

Comment: `sealed abstract case class` with a `private` constructor suppresses the auto-generated public `apply` method in the companion object.  It's a useful trick for getting [a useful subset of] `case class` semantics while enforcing invariants without throwing exceptions (e.g. to have the `apply` method return `Option`/`Try`/`Either`/Cats `Validated`/etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and apologies for the confusion. I was talking about non-abstract case classes which do have this issue, but that is clearly not a problem in this particular case. I have updated my own answer appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

This code compiles with no error:

```
 private sealed abstract case class Name(name: String)
```

The problem is that you are then returning a value that contains a `public` value of this class, so the definition is leaking out and it isn't really `private`. You need to make sure that all references to `Name` are also `private`.

The first syntax marks the constructor as private;

```
sealed abstract case class Name private(name: String)
```

This means that the constructor can only be called from inside the `Name` companion object. So this is not allowed

```
val name = new Name("name") // constructor Name in class Name cannot be accessed
```

Comment: That is incorrect.  Marking a `case class` `abstract` suppresses the companion `apply` (and the `copy` method).

Comment: While what I said is technically not incorrect (since I said `case class` rather than `abstract case class`) it certainly was confusing, for which I apologise. I have remove this from my answer but I am leaving the rest of the answer here as it explains the error the OP is seeing whereas the other answer does not.